# React native custom components: where does reactTag come from?

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I have looked at tutorial which uses

`-(void)mapView:(RCTMap *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

function and then emits event with `@"target": mapView.reactTag,`

or else, I've looked at some components like video or camera for react native where `@"target": self.reactTag` is used.

My question is: how to pass reactTag to these components? is there some naming convention? How should the reactTag be passed?

Answer (score -1):

What helped was to use react-native-video as template for structure (manager that passes eventDispatcher to component itself) and not forgetting `#import "UIView+React.h"`